# Setting state for toggle button value after change in NextJS/React

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a series of toggle buttons which toggle between values 'pending' and 'active'.
When onChange, I make a post request to update the value of the element that was toggled in the database. However, I want to be able to change the value of the element to its new value once toggled, locally.

I know I can use useState hooks, but the issue is that there can be potentially 100s of these elements, so I think that's out of question. Is there some other way I can update the value of the element?

This is what I'm currently working with

```
  const toggleChange = async (e) => {
    let elemId = e.target.id;
    let newStatus; 
    if (e.target.value === 'pending') {
      newStatus = 'active';
    } else if (e.target.value === 'active') {
      newStatus = 'pending';
    }
     
    // post request
    await updateStatus(elemId, newStatus);
  };



 return (
 ...
 <Switch
 onChange={(e) => {
     toggleChange(e);
  }}
  defaultChecked={status == 'active' ? true : false}
  id={elem_id}
  value={status}
 />
 )
```

Comment: Each `<Switch>` should manage its own state, then you won't have 100s of `useState`, but only one.

Comment: The issue is that <Switch> is actually a ChakraUI component that I'm using. However, I do think I can solve that issue by creating my own switch component using that. Thank you for your reply. I guess I might use this as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `useReducer` instead of `useState`

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

Comment: Is there another way without the use of Reducers? Because I'm actually using NextJS

Comment: theres no problem in using useReducer in NextJS, this is part of react, its not based on Redux... its just solution for "more complex state of component" not "whole app store"